# Filtering lines with some conditions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, overlapping-features, filter

I have two shape layers: a Polygon layer and a Line layer in QGIS.

I want to filter/highlight lines based on the following conditions:

- Case 1: Filter/highlight lines which cross all the polygons (like AND condition). Attribute by location feature is allowing filtering lines with just 1 cross.
- Case 2: Filter lines which start/end in the specified polygon.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. We are a *problem-solving* site, and in order to have a problem you first need to attempt to solve the task. Please [Edit] the Question to explain what you have attempted and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Answering to your first question:

Open the [Extract by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisextractbyexpression) tool.

1. Set as **Input layer** the line layer
2. Paste the following expression, remember to change `'Polygons layer name/id'` with your values, click OK and run:

   ```
   array_find(
       aggregate(
           'Polygon',
           'array_agg',
           num_points(intersection(geometry(@parent), exterior_ring($geometry))) > 1
       ),
       0
   ) = -1
   ```

About your second question, is not clear how are the start and end polygons specified, so I can't help you. Please expand your second question.

Comment: Hi. Why not just `intersects( $geometry, geometry(@parent))` as expression for the aggregate function? Also, you can check if `array_find(@t, 0)) = -1` (so 0 is not found), but mainly I don't understand why you want to make lines from polygons, make intersection geometries and count them to be more than one.

Comment: I think because you want to test "crosses" as "intersects two times with its boundary or exterior ring". There are already functions to extract boundary and exterior ring from polygons. Right now, the intersection with the polygon geometry will occur only one time. In your previous custom function, I don't know if the created linestring will be closed, also don't know if it follows the boundary in all cases (interior rings, multipart geometries).

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca, I rewrote the expression from scratch, thanks for the idea of ​​using `exterior_rings` and `array_find(array) = -1`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the line is `disjoint` from each of the polygons. Use this expression:

```
array_sum(
    array_foreach (
        aggregate ('polygon', 'array_agg',$geometry),
        disjoint ($geometry, @element)
    )
)=0
```

Explanation: it creates an array of all polygons, then checks for each polygon if it is disjoint from the current line. If it is disjoint from a polygon, it returns `1`, otherwise `0`. So if the array contains only elements of value `0`, it is not disjoint to any of the polygons = it intersects all polygons:

[image]

---

To get all lines that start or end in any specific polygon (here: the feature with `$id`=6), use this expression:

```
array_sum(
    array_foreach (
        array (start_point ($geometry),end_point ($geometry)),
        intersects (
            @element, 
            geometry (get_feature_by_id ('polygon',6)  -- replace 6 by the $id of the polygon feature
))))>0
```

*Start points of the line are indicated with a point symbol:*
[image]